# Can't cancel running AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm having some trouble with an AsyncTask subclass.

I have a main activity as below that displays a button and a number that counts up on the screen. Clicking the button launches an Edit activity where a number can be entered.

The number displayed on the Main activity should update with the timer which it does but the trouble I'm having is that I can't stop the timer. It should stop when entering the Edit activity and returning from it as well, as well as restart with the a new value too but it doesn't, the timer is always running with the first entered value, it never stops, even when I leave the program and return to the home screen.

I've looked at posts here such as [Can't cancel Async task in android](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279695/cant-cancel-async-task-in-android&ei=7-e3UqT7I4jikgWks4H4CQ&usg=AFQjCNH2wCR_MzkUyb4w1e3JC2wcI21HLg&bvm=bv.58187178,d.dGI&cad=rja) but they all just mention checking for isCancelled() which I'm doing. Can anyone see/explain why I can't stop this AsyncTask ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
UpdateTimer ut;
TextView tvn;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    tvn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numDisplay);

    if(ut != null )//&& ut.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
        ut.cancel(true);
        ut.cancelled = true;
        Log.d("-----M_r","called cancel: "+ut.isCancelled()+" "+cancelled);
    }

    if (updateRequired) {
        ut = new UpdateTimer();
        ut.execute(number);
        updateRequired = false;
    }
}

public void onEditButtonPressed(View caller) {

    // kill any running timer
    if(ut != null )
    {
        ut.cancel(true);
        ut.cancelled = true;
    }

    // start the edit screen
    Intent e_intent = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);
    startActivity(e_intent);
}

private void updateScreen(long number) {

    // update screen with current values
    tvn.setText("" + number);
}

private class UpdateTimer extends AsyncTask<Long, Long, Integer> {

    long number;
    public boolean cancelled;

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Long... params) {

        number = params[0];
        cancelled = false;

        while(true) {
            number += 1;

            //sleep for 1 second
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // tell this AsyncTask to update the time on screen
            publishProgress(number);

            // check if timer needs to stop
            if (isCancelled()) break;
            if(cancelled) break;
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress) {
            Log.d("-----M_ut","updated: "+number+"  "+this.isCancelled()+" "+cancelled);
        updateScreen(progress[0]);
    }

     protected void onCancelled(Integer result) {
         cancelled = true;
         Log.d("-----M_ut","-- cancelled called: "+this.isCancelled());
    }

}

protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();

    // kill any running timer
    if(ut != null) {
        ut.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
remove the variable..`cancelled` and change to this..

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    super.onCancelled();
}
```

call the `super.onCancelled` instead..

And in the `doInBackground` check

```
if (isCancelled()) {
    break;
}
```

Try calling from your activity `ut.cancel(true);`

Hope it works:)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work.
I forgot to mention before that the log lines all return true regarding isCancelled except for the one in onProgressUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

```
private YourAsyncTask ut;
```

declare your asyncTask in your activity.

> ```
> ut = new YourAsyncTask().execute();
> ```

instantiate it like this.

> ```
> ut.cancel(true);
> ```

kill/cancel it like this.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work.
I can't see why isCancelled returns true from everywhere else except doInBackground and onProgressUpdate.