# Boolean value does NOT change on clicking cancel button - How to stop AsyncTask - Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, boolean

I am a beginner, so please explain your answer clearly. Thanks

***EDIT 2***
I now have

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        //other declarations
        public ReadTask readTask;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     readTask = new ReadTask();

    private OnClickListener test = new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View V)
            {
                readTask.execute();
                //new ReadTask().execute();

            }

    };
    private OnClickListener cancel = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View V)
        {   
            readTask.cancel(true);
            results1.setText("");
        }
```

Check EDIT 1 for the error this code above (Edit 2) throws;
Thanks

> I have a cancel button in the App. On clicking this, this is what
>   happens;

```
    public void onClick (View V)
        {
                    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                       InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

            new ReadTask().onCancelled();
            new ReadTask().cancel(true);
            results1.setText("Cancelled");
        }
```

ReadTask extends AsyncTask like this;

```
public class ReadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>
    {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    public volatile boolean isCancelled=false;
    //other declarations
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        isCancelled = true;
        new ReadTask().cancel(true);
    }

 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
            // isCancelled=false;


        try {
            for(int k=x1[3];k<=x2[3];k++)
            {
                //bunch of code
            Log.w("5.newString", newString);
            String isC1 = String.valueOf(isCancelled);
            Log.w("5.Is cancelled?", isC1); // at this point, VALUE IS ALWAYS FALSE !

            if (isCancelled() || isCancelled == true) {Log.d("Entered","WHY");break;}

                //bunch of code

           } //bunch of catches
```

There are 2 methods tried here, one a boolean variable isCancelled and the other ReadTask().cancel(true); - Both don't work. Why?

I am a newcomer, so please explain your answer clearly. Thanks

************** EDIT 1 - Logcat Output*******

```
11-27 17:18:56.626: W/dalvikvm(28775): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bcee48)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775): Process: com.example.pingtest, PID: 28775
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pingtest/com.example.pingtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at com.example.pingtest.MainActivity$ReadTask.<init>(MainActivity.java:120)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at com.example.pingtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
11-27 17:18:56.636: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    ... 11 more
11-27 17:19:05.665: I/Process(28775): Sending signal. PID: 28775 SIG: 9
```

---

Comment: What do you WANT to happen?

Comment: Also, have you tested the button first? To make sure your calls to cancel are even being executed?

Comment: I want the boolean value (isCancelled) to change to True after clicking on the button. Please, also read the comments in the code. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the button works, but the value remains unchanged. I WANT to stop the AsynTask that's running after clicking on the cancel button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i made some changes in your code with explanation please check.

```
 public class Asyn extends Activity {

    public ReadTask readTask;
    // keep global to prevent creating new async task on every time button click
    boolean isCancelled = true;
    TextView results1;
    Button start, end;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.qww);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        end = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        start.setOnClickListener(test);
        end.setOnClickListener(cancel);
        results1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    private OnClickListener test = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View V) {
            if (isCancelled) { // checked to prevent creating new async task on
                                // every time button click
                Toast.makeText(Asyn.this, "new task started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                readTask = new ReadTask();
                readTask.execute();
                isCancelled = false;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Asyn.this, "Task already runing",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    };
    private OnClickListener cancel = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View V) {
            if (null != readTask) {
                Toast.makeText(Asyn.this, "Task stop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                readTask.cancel(true);
                isCancelled = true;
            }
            results1.setText("");
        }
    };

        private class ReadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {


    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
         super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        results1.setText(values[0].toString());


    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            for (int k = 0; k <= 10; k++) {
                // bunch of code
                Log.w("5.newString", k + "");
                String isC1 = String.valueOf(isCancelled);
                Log.w("5.Is cancelled?", isC1); // at this point, VALUE IS


                    //below line for instant update as soon as the value is changed
                 publishProgress("  "+k + "");

                // use thread to see the update otherwise remove it
                    Thread.sleep(2000); 
                if (isCancelled() || isCancelled == true) {
                    Log.d("Entered", "WHY");
                    break;
                }

                // bunch of code

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // assign true to isCancelled so that user can start task again
        isCancelled = true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, everytime I enter "public ReadTask readTask;" on MainActivty, the app does not even start. FATAL EXCEPTION:main. If I comment that out and instantiate a new readTask on each (test and cancel buttons), the app. runs. The class looks like this-  public class "ReadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>". Please tell me why this happens. Thanks.

Comment: Please make the ReadTask class private because it is inner class,i already edited it.Can you explain me whether you want to create new task on every button click or same async task.currently it creating only one instance.

Comment: I only need 1 async task and I want this async task to cancel when I tap my cancel button. At the moment, the cancel works, HOWEVER, it only cancels the task AFTER it has completed a current loop inside the doInBackground() task. How to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You are a saver Chandra! - I had FAILED to initialize readTask in my onCreate() method. Now, works perfectly. Stops within the loop. I can't believe I commented that line. Thanks again for your help. The only problem now is that the STR that gets passed to the onProgressUpdate() method only gets printed to my UI Once after the loop ends... I want it to print everytime a line comes in.

Comment: Pl. check these questions - they have more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198413/how-to-display-the-ping-output-line-by-line-android-java?noredirect=1#comment42904451_27198413 AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197837/in-asynctask-how-to-pass-data-from-doinbackground-to-main-ui-instantly-and-n/27203117?noredirect=1#comment42894897_27203117

Comment: i have modified the code.Hope it will help you.better you used ProgressDialog so that user can get proper intimation that something is updating. please go through this link.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Hi, I am already passing a string. Please look at this code to see how I am passing it. ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197837/in-asynctask-how-to-pass-data-from-doinbackground-to-main-ui-instantly-and-n/27203117?noredirect=1#comment42894897_27203117 ) Is there sth I am missing? Added the Thread.sleep(2000) but it still only sends out the string value after one iteration of the FOR loop. I want it to update sooner than that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because each time you are creating new object from `ReadTask`. if you want to cancel existing job. you should do this :

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
   ReadTask readTask; 

   @Override
   public void onCreate (Bundle b) {
       ...
       readTask = new ReadTask();

       btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override 
          void onClick(View v) {
            readTask.execute();
          }
       }

       btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override 
          void onClick(View v) {
            readTask.cancel();
          }
       }
   }

 }
```

Comment: Yep, i concur, i missed it the first time.

Comment: No, the ReadTask.execute() is started by clicking on a different button on the app. I don't want to start another thread by clicking on the cancel button. I want to stop the existing one. Do you understand?

Comment: that's what I'm saying. you should define your object in your class and in your cancel button's onClick method, call cancel for that object and DON'T create new object. am I clear?

Comment: If I do ReadTask readTask = new ReadTask(); under MainActivity, the App does not launch, I get a "FATAL exception:main" error in Logcat.

Comment: I tried it just like your example, with readTask = new ReadTask(); inside the bundle and ReadTask readTask; inside the MainActivity. readTask.execute(); inside the first button and readTask.cancel(true); inside the CANCEL button. But a FATAL EXCEPTION:main occurs and the app does not even start. Why?

Comment: post your logcat output please.

Comment: Hello, please let me know - it's a Null Pointer Exception and I don't know why it gets thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
new ReadTask().onCancelled();
new ReadTask().cancel(true);
```

this part of your code is wrong for both of them refers to different instance of ReadTask class.
you can declare a global variable of ReadTask class

```
public ReadTask rt;
```

and initialize it on your `onCreate()` method.

```
rt = new ReadTask();
```

then you can already use it on every part of your activity
start it using `rt.execute()` and stop it using `rt.cancel(true)`

Comment: Hi, I did it and if I do this, I get a NULL pointer exception and the app. does not start.

Comment: I tried it just like your example, with readTask = new ReadTask(); inside the bundle and ReadTask readTask; inside the MainActivity. readTask.execute(); inside the first button and readTask.cancel(true); inside the CANCEL button. But a FATAL EXCEPTION:main (Null pointer exception) occurs and the app does not even start. Why?

Comment: Hi, I can't share the entire code, most of it is in the question. The change is, I have a  "ReadTask readTask;" inside the MainActivity. A "readTask = new ReadTask();" inside the bundle.  "readTask.execute();" inside the first button and "readTask.cancel(true);" inside the CANCEL button. Also, the Edit in the question shows the LogCat output.