# In AsyncTask How to pass data from doInBackground() to main UI "instantly" and not after each loop? (BufferedReader)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, bufferedreader, stringbuffer

**EDIT1:**

I did change the code such that the update was done within the while loop. HOWEVER, NO CHANGE. SHOWN THIS IN CODE BELOW. ALSO, removed other irrelevant lines on onProgressUpdate().
SHOWN IN CODE BELOW.

Please answer like you would teach an amateur. 
I am passing data from doInBackground() to the main UI currently. It works. However, it is very slow. 
I want to display "instant" results and not after the loop completes. That's how the code is written, however, performance wise, if the loop runs for 100 times, I only get the results AT once after 100 iterations are complete. This is weird. I want results output after every iteration. How to achieve this. 
Currently;

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {

            try {
    //bunch of code
for(int k=x1[3];k<=x2[3];k++)
            {
//Process process = execute it;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                    int j;
                    char[] buffer = new char[4096];
                    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((j = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
                    {
                    output.append(buffer, 0, j); 
                    }
                    str = output.toString();
                    Log.d("1:STR VALUE", str);
                    publishProgress(str);
                    reader.close();  

    } //FOR loop ends
                 }}
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            results1.append(str);
            results1.append("\n");
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
```

How to modify the StringBuffer output such that I get instant results after the reader gets the data?
Thanks

Comment: Have you consider using runOnUiThread inside doInBackground?

Comment: No, I don't know how to do it. Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: code is ok may be your x1[3] and x2[3] values are same that's why it running only one time. try to replace with different no and debug it .it working properly.

Comment: Hi Sir, no x1[3] gets incremented by 1 until it reaches x2[3] - the loop does run several times. However, the output STR only gets sent to the UI once every time the loop runs. For ex: 1 output after x1[3] completes, 1 output after x1[3]++ completes untill x2[3]. I want the STR values to get passed "instantly" as they come in. Not after the loop. Hope u understand my question. Thanks for the help. This is another question I posted reg. this: please look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198413/how-to-display-the-ping-output-line-by-line-android-java?noredirect=1#comment42884148_27198413

Answer (score 0):

`onProgressUpdate` runs in the UI thread.

So you should be able to interact with the UI with this method, inside your loop. However, try to use the given parameter of the method :

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values)
{
    results1.append(values[0]);
    results1.append("\n");
}
```

Calling `super.onProgressUpdate(values);` is useless as the default implementation is empty.

Comment: I just made the change and it made no difference to the output. The results are being displayed after the entire process is completed. The process here can be taken as a PING. I want it to display after every packet is sent. NOT after the 100 pings are completed. Although the code looks like it's passing the values out, it isn't.

Comment: Thanks, but I am confused. Pl. clarify. results1.append(values[0]) is how it is used. From the BUTTON click, I use the following:  if (isCancelled) 
    { // checked to prevent creating new async task every time button is clicked
    // Toast.makeText(readTask.this, "new task started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     ReadTask readTask = new ReadTask();
     readTask = new ReadTask();
     readTask.execute();
     isCancelled = false;
    } else {
     //Toast.makeText(Asyn.this, "Task already running",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

Comment: You are modifying `result1`, this means this variable is used on the UI thread somehow, isn't it ?

Comment: Hi, results1 is just a TextView in the UI and I append to it in the onProgressUpdate method.

Comment: Try results1.setText(result1.getText().toString() + values[0] + "\n");

Comment: Thanks, but please be more clear. I have no variable called "result1". There is a TextView called "results1" (plural).

Comment: It's my mistake, try results1.setText(results1.getText().toString() + values[0] + "\n");

Comment: Just tried it. Absolutely no change. It still displays only after that for loop fully completes. I don't know why.

Comment: I made a change to the code. Now you can see where the While loop ends. Sorry for the confusion. Please help. thanks.